# PDF multipage not create in android

Tags: java, android, pdf-generation, itext

Create PDF in android but create only one page and my other data are not see. how to auto increment PDF page runtime in android.any idea or suggestion.My problem is how to create a PDF with multiple pages from that Graphics object

Comment: Your question is unclear. New pages are created automatically if there is more data then there is space on a single page. You mention a `Graphics` object. I assume that you refer to `PdfGraphics2D`. However, you also mention Android. There is no `Graphics2D` on Android, so your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

Create PDF in android with Multiple pages use this library

put this gradle file in your apps build.gradle file
-- compile 'com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:5.5.8'

Use this code for generate pdf with multiple pages

1. tempArrayList - array of file path.
2. pdfName - pdf name as you wish.

   ```
   generatePDF(String pdf_name) {

     String pdfName= null;
     Dialog  dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(activity)
           .backgroundColor(Color.WHITE).contentColor(Color.BLACK).title(getString(R.string.app_name)).titleColor(Color.BLACK)
           .content("Generating pdf...").progress(true, 0)
           .show();

    dialog.setCancelable(false);

     pdfName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".pdf";

   File myPath = new File(AppConstant.Pdf_Directory, pdfName);
   if (myPath.exists()) {
       myPath.delete();
   }

   Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4); // create the document

   try {
       PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(myPath));
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }

   // open document
   document.open();

   for (int i = 0; i < tempArrayList.size(); i++) {

       Bitmap bmp = null;
       try {
           bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempArrayList.get(i));
           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
           Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

           if (image.getWidth() >= document.getPageSize().getWidth() || image.getHeight() >= document.getPageSize().getHeight()) {
               image.scaleToFit(document.getPageSize());
           }

           image.setAbsolutePosition((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - image.getScaledWidth()) / BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_MEDIUM, (document.getPageSize().getHeight() - image.getScaledHeight()) / BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_MEDIUM);
           document.add(image);
           document.newPage();

       } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
           Toast.makeText(activity, "Fail to generate pdf.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       if (bmp != null) {
           bmp.recycle();
       }
   }
   // close the document
   document.close();

   Toast.makeText(activity, "Pdf generate successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   System.out.println(" pdf generate ");

   dialog.dismiss();
   ```

   }

Comment: "thank u for the reply I have try this code but not effect."

Comment: @Ravimakhija Please understand that this is a good answer to a bad question. Using `newPage()` triggers a new page. Obviously, you shouldn't copy/paste this snippet and expect it to work as it involves an array of images. Nowhere in your question do you refer to images, so you probably have to adapt this example. The most essential line in this example is `document.newPage()`.